# Delphi create a Inifile

Tags: delphi, ini

I want to create/write an inifile in Delphi but it doesn't work.
To write/create a inifile I use this script:

```
ini := TIniFile.Create('Test.ini');
try
ini.WriteInteger('Test', 'Port', 33645);
ini.WriteBool('Test', 'ListenOnStart', true);
ini.WriteBool('Test', 'UpdateCheck', true);
ini.UpdateFile;
finaly
ini.free;
end;
```

I get the error "Unable to write to Test.ini.", when I execute it as admin I don't get this error but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I suggest to reword the question and remove everything irrelevant (ini file and code)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not specifying the full path to your ini file so the program will attempt to save it in the Windows directory, which your app does not have access to write to.  Solve your problem by specifying the full path to the ini file instead.  But use a full path that your app actually has write access to, such as a subfolder within the user's profile, like in MyDocuments or AppData.

Since the program failed with an access denied error as standard user, but succeeded as an admin user it seems likely that you have actually saved the file to the Windows directory. Look there to find your stray ini file. You'll almost certainly want to delete it from your system.

Comment: Thanks I now use
ini := Tinifile.Create(ChangeFileExt(Application.ExeName,'.ini'));

Comment: You'll want to tidy up the stray file which you probably into a system directory by mistake.

Comment: @jwz: Probably yout EXE resides in the program files folder, which you do not normally have write access to. Hence, the operating system will put your INI file in a 'vritual store' folder instead. It is much better if you use the roaming app data folder to store your INI file. (Of course, if your application is a portable one, these remarks do not apply.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand If it was going in the virtual store, then the program would not fail as standard user. So it would seem that user has a manifest and so is not virtualized. I think windows directory is more likely because it seems that it can be saved into executable directory fine. Which is most likely writeable because it will be under the development tree.

Comment: @David: Yeah, I understand that. My remark was more targeted at the `Tinifile.Create(ChangeFileExt(Application.ExeName,'.ini'));` suggestion (and the final location of the EXE on the end user system).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: your solution is right (use a full path), but your diagnosis is a little off. A relative path for an INI file is relative to the *Windows directory*, not the CWD. The app likely does not have write access to the Windows directory, thus the "unable to write" error. `TIniFile.Write...()` uses the `WritePrivateProfileString()` API: "*If the lpFileName parameter does not contain a full path and file name for the file, **WritePrivateProfileString searches the Windows directory for the file. If the file does not exist, this function creates the file in the Windows directory**.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you very much for that correction, and your edit. I was not aware of that nuance, and I appreciate you teaching me something new!